# Webdrivercss socket closed error running on windows 7

Tags: windows, selenium, webdriver-io

I have installed webdrivercss and webdriverjs on my Windows 7(32 bit) machine. When i try to run a basic test as below, it always gives socket closed error.

I checked the selenium server output, it seems like everything is running fine until it reach the point to take screenshot and save it. The folder for screenshot root is already created. I actually use webdriverjs to successfully take a screenshot and save it. So there shouldn't be any write issues.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Below is my testing file: 'test_webdrivercss.js'

```
// init WebdriverJS
var client = require('webdriverjs').remote({  
host: 'localhost',
port: 4444})
// init WebdriverCSS
require('webdrivercss').init(client, {
    // example options
    screenshotRoot: 'my-shots',
    failedComparisonsRoot: 'diffs',
    misMatchTolerance: 0.05,
    screenWidth: [320,480,640,1024]
});

client
    .init()
    .url('http://example.com')
    .webdrivercss('headerArea')
    .end();
```

Below is the error output:

```
    C:\webdrivercss\node_modules\webdriverjs\examples>node test_webdrivercss.js

    events.js:72
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
    Error: This socket is closed.
        at Socket._write (net.js:637:19)
        at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
        at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
        at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
        at Socket.write (net.js:615:40)
        at gm._spawn (C:\webdrivercss\node_modules\webdrivercss\node_modules\gm\lib\
    command.js:195:18)
        at C:\webdrivercss\node_modules\webdrivercss\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:
    78:12
        at series (C:\webdrivercss\node_modules\webdrivercss\node_modules\gm\node_mo
    dules\array-series\index.js:11:36)
        at gm._preprocess (C:\webdrivercss\node_modules\webdrivercss\node_modules\gm
    \lib\command.js:154:5)
        at gm.write (C:\webdrivercss\node_modules\webdrivercss\node_modules\gm\lib\c
    ommand.js:76:10)

    C:\webdrivercss\node_modules\webdriverjs\examples>
```

Btw, I did the test with a local selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0 server running.

I opened an issue on webdrivercss github here:https://github.com/webdriverjs/webdrivercss/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

I see you have already received help on the webdrivercss github, but I'm going to repeat and expand on the answer you received here for other who might have this issue.

The problem is related to GraphicsMagick, which should be installed prior to running webdrivercss. It can be found [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html). In my case, I already had the 64bit version of GraphicsMagick installed, and it didn't work, so I tried uninstalling it and then installing the 32bit version and it did work.